# Why my while loop iteration is 15 times instead of 10?

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$j = array('U1','U2','U3','U4','U5');
while ($i <= 10) {
    foreach ($j as $value) {
        $i++;
        echo "$i $value <br>";
    }
}
```

?>

// output
1 U1
2 U2
3 U3
4 U4
5 U5
6 U1
7 U2
8 U3
9 U4
10 U5
11 U1
12 U2
13 U3
14 U4
15 U5

I want my loop iteration is 10 time

Comment: You have two loops: while and for each. So you run 10 times foreach loop of 5 item array but every loop you increment the counter $i and the final result is 15. What you want to print in the screen? 10 times the entire array?

Comment: Second time the `foreach` finishes `$i` will be `10`, which makes `$i <= 10` true, so it runs a third time, making it 15, ending the `while` loop

Comment: Because you add $i++ inside the loop, first of echo statement. So second time for each finishes the value of $i is 9. Change the while statement to 9 and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is running 15 times because it's 2 loops. It actually doesn't run 15 times, but 3 times. That's because every time you make it run, it prints the entire array. So, for every array item, `$i` is increased by 5. Let me explain:

1. You set `$i` to 0
2. You set an array with 5 items
3. While `$i` is less than or equal to 10 you:

   1. For every item of the array (in your case 5 times) do:

      1. Increase `$i` by 1
      2. Print `$i` and the key of the array item you are reading.

So `$i` is increased by 5 every time the foreach loop is run.
To fix this:
DO NOT use a for() loop. Just do this:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$j = array('U1','U2','U3','U4','U5');
while ($i <= 10) {
    foreach ($j as $value) {
        echo "$i $value <br>";
        $i++;
    }
}?>
```

So what has changed? the `$i` starts at 1 and it is increased after it is printed. Output:

```
1 U1
2 U2
3 U3
4 U4
5 U5
6 U1
7 U2
8 U3
9 U4
10 U5
```

--Solved--

Another solution is to start `$i` from 0 and increase it BEFORE it is printed. Code:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$j = array('U1','U2','U3','U4','U5');
while ($i < 10) {
    foreach ($j as $value) {
        $i++;
        echo "$i $value <br>";
    }
}?>
```

Output:

```
1 U1
2 U2
3 U3
4 U4
5 U5
6 U1
7 U2
8 U3
9 U4
10 U5
```

Comment: "_and increase it BEFORE it is printed_" That seems like the wrong explanation. It works because of `$i < 10`

Comment: Nope... It's not a wrong explanation. the original one first prints it and then increases it. Here, it first increases it and then prints it. If you tried it, or just thought about it, the original with printing first prints the first number as 0 U1. I print it as 1 U1.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use a foreach loop inside the while loop. Just before the third loop $i is actually less or equal to 10. But then you run the foreach loop against the array. I would suggest to just use a basic for loop. It would also make the code look a lot cleaner.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($j)*2; $i++) 
 { //execute code 
 }
```

This Will ensure the iteration of the array is run exactly 10 times. This solution is only useful if the array size is constant and doesn’t change.

Answer (score 0):

you should start initializing $i = 1 instead of $i = 0
you can check yourself by changing the value in loop.
For example in your code  you put i<=1 , your all elements in an arrary runs to 5 times, if you put i<=5, it runs upto 10.

Also you have printed value after incrementing i value.

This is the solution for above problems.

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$j = array('U1','U2','U3','U4','U5');
while ($i <= 10) {
    foreach ($j as $value) {
        echo "$i $value <br>";
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

Output

```
1 U1
2 U2
3 U3
4 U4
5 U5
6 U1
7 U2
8 U3
9 U4
10 U5
```

Answer (score -1):

Please below code which will run as per you expectation.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$j = array('U1','U2','U3','U4','U5');
foreach ($j as $value) {
    while ($i < 10) {
        $i++;
        echo "$i $value <br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Not OPs expectation. This will print `U1` ten times